# Is there a way to retrieve the fund back from the contract to Metamask wallet

Tags: remix

Used remixethereumcompiler.io to deploy a bot contract. The contract address shows in etherscan. didn't use any of the bot functions like Start or Withdraw function so the funds didn't get transferred to the scammer's address.

Used remixethereum.org and AT Address under Deploy  with the bot contract address. Get the message that 'No compiled contracts found'. Is there a way to retrieve the fund back from the contract to Metamask wallet.

Comment: Nope. I have seen this multiple time. Lot's of ppl get scam with that fake bot. Your funds are lost unless you edited the contract before deployment.

For a better answer please provide the contract and it's address.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The contract address is: 0x4Dc4cAf17796cd39C99b47335cc549E441D47515

Comment: I can see that there is a balance of 0.7 eth at this address but I'm not able to see the actual code of the contract. You could verify the contract so etherscan show the full code or post the contract here.

Comment: Here is the link to code: https://pastebin.com/raw/M6mEnfB3

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, your funds are lost. Anything sent to this contract is not withdraw able.

When deploying a contract, you should always ensure that you have a way to withdraw token or ether from it.

Comment: Thanks for checking this out. Lesson learned.

Answer (score 0):

there is no way to withdraw fund from smart contract if you are not create any withdraw function before deployment

i think next time you don't make this mistake also use testnet for verification of smart contract
for now there is no way
your fund is lost
no one can do anything

in future if you have any problem then ask any good developer before putting your real money...